# Unable to access a multipart non-file field in Vapor 2

Tags: php, vapor

I have a macOS application written in Objective-C that uploads a file to a server using a multipart request. It stores the file data in a field called 'document and it puts an additional field, 'database' into the header:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"document\"; database=\"%s\"\r\n", DATABASE] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

I am writing a Vapor replacement for the simplistic scripts I have been using for a few years. In PHP on the server, to extract the value of the field 'database', I use:

```
$database = $_FILES['document']['database'];
```

I cannot find a way of doing the same in Vapor. I can happily unpack the file itself using:

```
guard let filebytes = req.formData?["document"]?.part.body else ...
```

I have tried changing the order of the fields, etc. Has anyone done this? Or is there a better way of creating the request in the first place? Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I have made some progress:

```
req.formData?["document"]?.part.headers["Content-Disposition"]
```

gives

```
"form-data; database=\"test\"; name=\"document\""
```

Now just got to extract the bit I'm interested in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the only non-file field you can set/access for Vapor is one called `filename` in a `multipart/form-data`. So, I achieved what I wanted to do by adding another part and putting the fields in this.